# AWS .NET SDK SimpleEmail SendEmail returning 'Could not load type' error

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm developing an application using AWS SimpleEmail. I'm getting the error below when I try to test SendEmail function.

> Could not load type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.InvokeOptions' from
>   assembly 'AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604'.

I have AWSSDK.Core v3.3.31.7 and AWSSDK.SimpleEmail v3.3.7.30 installed.

```
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("key", "secret");

var client = new Amazon.SimpleEmail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

var sesResponse = client.SendEmail(new SendEmailRequest
{
    Destination = new Destination
    {
        BccAddresses = new List<string>
        {

        },
        ToAddresses = new List<string> {
            "user@cuchuma.net",
            "user2@cuchuma.net"
        }
    },
    Message = new Message
    {
        Body = new Body
        {
            Html = new Content
            {
                Charset = "UTF-8",
                Data = "This message body contains HTML formatting. It can, for example, contain links like this one: <a class=\"ulink\" href = \"http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide\" target = \"_blank\"> Amazon SES Developer Guide </a>."
            },
            Text = new Content
            {
                Charset = "UTF-8",
                Data = "This is the message body in text format."
            }
        },
        Subject = new Content
        {
            Charset = "UTF-8",
            Data = "Test email"
        }
    },
    ReplyToAddresses = new List<string>
    {

    },
    ReturnPath = "",
    ReturnPathArn = "",
    Source = "no-reply@cuchuma.net",
    SourceArn = ""
});

string messageId = sesResponse.MessageId;
```

Comment: What version of .net is your project built in?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class it cannot load was only added  [2 months ago](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Internal/InvokeOptions.cs). So my suspicion is that you have an older version of AWSSDK.Core than you have stated (v3.3.31.7).

Now I'm not sure how this happens, but I have seen instances in the past where Nuget gets messed up and a manual entry in the project file causes an incorrect dll to be loaded.

Open up your project file in notepad and look for the SDK references. They should look like the following:

```
<Reference Include="AWSSDK.Core, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\AWSSDK.Core.3.3.31.7\lib\net45\AWSSDK.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="AWSSDK.SimpleEmail, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=885c28607f98e604, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\AWSSDK.SimpleEmail.3.3.7.30\lib\net45\AWSSDK.SimpleEmail.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Check to see that the package names are indeed AWSSDK.Core.3.3.31.7 and AWSSDK.SimpleEmail.3.3.7.30.

Also check that there are no other random AWSSDK.Core entries.

Lastly... Another issue you might run into, if you don't specify them then don't include the following lines with blank string. It will throw an invalid email address error:

```
ReturnPath = "",
ReturnPathArn = "",
SourceArn = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation of @Martin Beeby's answer.

Using the [`fuslogvw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer?redirectedfrom=MSDN) tool I saw that the GAC version of AWSSDK.Core is loaded before attempting to load the local copy. My GAC had an outdated version of the AWSSDK.Core assembly and worse I could not safely uninstall it because there were dependencies.  What ended up working was: I navigated to the local copy in my project (something like `<solution folder>/packages/AWSSDK.Core.3.5.3.1/`) and with an elevated PowerShell prompt I issued:

`&"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\gacutil.exe" /i .\AWSSDK.Core.dll`

so that the newer version gets installed, and the error went away.

Note: you might have `gacutil` in a different path and it might even be on the `path` environment variable so you don't need a path.